# how to fix Undefined index error without error_reporting(0) function

Tags: php

i have a form like the one below

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']=="submit")
{
   echo "hi";
   die();
}
?>


<form action="" method="post">
   name : <input type="text" name="fname" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

when i click on submit button it works fine but on page load it shows the following error..

```
Notice: Undefined index: Submit in C:\wamp\www\practie\index.php on line 4
```

i know this can be resolved by using `error_reporting(0)` function..but is there any other way to remove this error??

any help will be appreciated ..thanks

Comment: Your code is fine. Check again.

Comment: i have edited my code ..pleae see to it..it is giving error

Answer (score 1):

Update the condition as :

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['submit']))
     {

      echo "hi";
      die();
     }
?>
```